# Несколько меню в одном SlickNav

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Постараюсь вкратце описать суть проблемы:
У меня есть мобильное меню, подключенное с помощью плагина *SlickNav*.

Мне нужно в этом меню создать ещё одно выпадающее меню с произвольным названием.
Вот мой код:

```
var combinedMenu = $('.super-menu').clone(); //Это основное меню, которое я инициализирую
var secondMenu = $('.side-category-left:first-child .box-category ul').clone(); //Это пункты меню, которые мне нужно добавить в созданное мною меню с названием "Каталог"

var combmenu = $(combinedMenu.append('<li>Каталог<ul></ul></li>')); //Создаю пункт меню в переменной с названием "Каталог" и вложенным списком ul, в который хочу добавить li из переменной secondMenu

secondMenu.children('li').appendTo(combmenu); //Пытаюсь добавить дочерные элементы в созданное меню "Каталог"

combinedMenu.slicknav({
  duplicate: false,
  label: ''
});
```

Проблема в том, что элементы вставляются после моего меню. Как мне вставить `secondMenu.children('li')` в `ul` переменной combmenu ?

Очень нужна помощь. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Только, что ответил почти на такой же вопрос.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/620022/189649
Там я создаю в конце `<li>Новое меню</li>`, потом через селектор нахожу этот пункт и в него вставляю нужный мне список. Браузер сам разберется как вставить ваш узел.

Не нужно для него создавать `<ul></ul>` или же ищите таким способом `li > ul`, а так вы там находили только li а ul нет, поэтому он вставлялся в конце li, а не в ul.