# Как создать элемент списка через jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как через jquery в .menu ul создать структуру вложенный список чтобы получилось вот так:

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Пункт 1</li>
      <li>Пункт 2</li>
      <li>Пункт 3</li>
      <li>Пункт 4</li>
      <li>Пункт 5</li>
      <li>Новый список<ul class="newmenu"></ul></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

И в этот класс .newmenu добавить дочерние элементы  из second-menu .

Пример:

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Пункт 1</li>
      <li>Пункт 2</li>
      <li>Пункт 3</li>
      <li>Пункт 4</li>
      <li>Пункт 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>



<div class="second-menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Пункт 21</li>
      <li>Пункт 22</li>
      <li>Пункт 23</li>
      <li>Пункт 24</li>
      <li>Пункт 25</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Если вкратце: есть меню, в котором нужно создать ещё одно произвольное меню и в него через jquery вытащить li из другого места.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const firstMenu = $('.menu > ul');
const secondMenu = $('.second-menu > ul');

firstMenu.append('<li>Новое меню</li>');
firstMenu.children('li:last-child').append(secondMenu);
$('.second-menu').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Пункт 1</li>
      <li>Пункт 2</li>
      <li>Пункт 3</li>
      <li>Пункт 4</li>
      <li>Пункт 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>



<div class="second-menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Пункт 21</li>
      <li>Пункт 22</li>
      <li>Пункт 23</li>
      <li>Пункт 24</li>
      <li>Пункт 25</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```